# aws, django, unicorn and s3 - do I need nginx then?

Tags: django, amazon-s3, nginx, amazon-web-services

I'm building app in django which I want to deploy on aws ec2 server. The app will run on gunicorn, and I want to place static files on s3. So my question is - do I need to use nginx at all?

Is there any other benefit of using nginx beside serving static files?

Arek

Comment: after skimming 2 books about nginx - I can say there is much more in it then static files serving, and as Sid mentioned the gunicorn docs (http://gunicorn.org/deploy.html) suggest putting nginx in front of their server (slow client buffering). Thank you guys.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/331256/why-do-i-need-nginx-and-something-like-gunicorn/331263#331263 - good explanetion from gunicorn developer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting nginx in the front of your stack not only allows you to route static content requests to your s3 storage but also give you the ability to do things like caching your django requests and lower the hits in your app and database. You can set up fine grain cache policies and have more control of exactly where requests will go, all while still under the same url structure as your set up in django.

Comment: Wouldn't it be slow to route your static content to s3 by way of nginx?

Comment: It's really up to the application to embed urls directly to the s3. It can either be a thing that nginx resolves by subdomain or url match, or something where the application actually uses s3 urls that never come back through nginx.

Comment: i feel like this is very directed towards media static, but for the generic styles on big projects like instagram i wonder if the standard is linking s3 trhough nginx or embeded s3 urls

Comment: @Mr-Programs this is a 7 year old answer. I'm sure there are AWS-provided load balancing, routing, and caching options as opposed to nginx. But my answer still stands that nginx can offer more benefit than just routing static content. It can do TLS termination before your app. And it can cache dynamic content.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you're placing static files on S3, you still need a web server to serve them, right? I don't see how S3 changes the fact that with Apache/WSGI or gunicorn it's better to have something like nginx serving static files. 
Also, read this: http://gunicorn.org/deploy.html

Comment: If the static files are on S3, then they'll be served from S3, not the app server, anyway.

Comment: Yes but what is routing requests to the s3 static location? It would not be ideal for him to use some kind of s3 absolute url. He ahould use nginx to map all static content under his domain to his s3

Comment: mipadi is right - s3 serves the files, I get a link to them and I don't care how they are served

Comment: @jdi - using route 53 (aws dns server or any other dns server probably) I can map the urls to smth like this : static.maindomain.com/filename - or any other url - what is wrong with this?

Comment: Yes but now you will have to hard code s3 urls into your templates. You no longer get that really great benefit of using the static django var for the dev server and then also having it work in production.

Comment: @jdi - isn't the "STATIC_URL = '/static/'" setting for this? I'll set this to 'static.maindomain.com' - and I'm all set :) ???

Comment: @jdi: Sure you do -- just set the `STATIC_URL` to the base of the S3 bucket. Or, as **agend** notes, you can map a subdomain like `media.example.com` to an S3 bucket, and use `media.example.com` as the value for `STATIC_URL`.

Comment: Ya i guess that does work :) does aws give you a caching layer like nginx?

Comment: I still feel it could be useful to use nginx. In case you have issues with S3 or your storage cost is proving to be a lot and you wanna switch to something else, you will be ready for it.

Comment: i want to add, i saw a company where you could upload a .csv to the s3, somehow you could request this file even when null, and the s3 was serving a xml that was rendered as tree, for such a case a nginx intermediate that would delivery the files would have been helpful i think, therefore the error xml wouldnt have been rendered